# Violation of trademark/Patent?

Tags: patent-infringement, patent-applications, licensing, infringement, trademark

In my National and PCT International, patent specification I have included an apparatus called Annular finned-tube heat exchanger, which is new in design. This heat exchanger is ring/annular like in shape. There is an existing research on Annular-finned tube heat exchanger, but it defines the shape of the tube as annular (indicated by the - in Annular-finned, whereas in my case its Annular finned-tube). These are 2 different products which are/look completely different. I have elaborated the construction and manufacturing of my apparatus. In my patent specification, the Annular finned-tube heat exchanger is one of the sub-component of the apparatus described.

There is no trademark or patent on Annular-finned tube heat exchanger. Even if we assume that there is one trademark in process which is unpublished, can there be a violation problem in future considering everything of the above?

I still have 9 days to amend the application, if required.